# How to allow other app to access my apis [express.js]

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, access-token

I already have API created with JWT tokens.

and user now can create POST request with user and pass to get Access token to get access to protected routes.

And now I need to allow another api to use my api how can I do it?

I am using node.js, express.js and jsonwebtoken node lib

Comment: Since you currently are using OAuth2.0 with token authentication (via the Password Grant), are you looking for advice on what form of OAuth2 to use? (EG: Client Credentials?) Or are you just looking for libraries / tools recommendations?

Comment: I don't use `OAuth` I am using JWT simple lib. I am looking for idea, how should it be done?

Comment: Sorry not JWT simple but `jsonwebtoken` lib

Comment: What do you mean when you say "another API to use my API"?

Comment: Just as it say... 1st API should take data from 2nd API, but 1st API should be authorized to take data from 2nd API.